# Google Maps looks shifted/moved (different columns are moved)

Tags: ipad, maps

I have a question about Google Maps. 
I integrated Google Maps in a one-page website.
The website contains a jQuery accordion etc. 
On a desktop the Google Maps is working fine, but when I look on a mobile device like an iPad, the map looks shifted. The maps is devided in two or three strokes, which are moved relative to each other.
I already tried a resize event, such as:
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
But this didn't work.

I don't have any idea what else I can try.

Comment: Have you set the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)?

Comment: Yes I did, maybe it will be helpful to know the website URL: http://angela.at20.vps.atention.nl/

Comment: There is no map in that link.... and I cant read that language (is that Swede or something?)

Comment: There sure is a map, but you have to click on Contact (in the upper menu on the right). I can image you can't read it, its Dutch.

Comment: ... just link it as `http://angela.at20.vps.atention.nl/#5` then...Also describe your issue with more details...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mediaquery system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to put the map in the desired position if the width is lesser than x (I go for 599 / 600 pixels in my queries)

Comment: I've tried that a few minutes ago. The height of the map is 20% of the container height (except the menu bar at the top and the footer). The width is 100%. Maybe the viewport width or viewport height (vw/vh) are causing this problem? But when I don't use them, the map is still not working

Comment: You have lots of other content that could be pushing/moving the map itself. As far as I can tell, the google engine is being rendered correct, but the map (in the div `three_fifth`) is out of the screen... Again, if you open your page, change the "slide", then resize the page, everything gets out of place, not just the map

Comment: Maybe this is my fault by forgetting something to tell. I builded the page like this: the website should work fine by a resolution greater than 1024px wide. For screens smaller than 1024px wide, I used a PHP user-agent detector to give the iPad and iPhone specific @media queries. Like this way I can target these devices specifically. Otherwise, by using this media query from big (1024px) to small (640px), I would have a problem with the landscape mode from the iPhone (the lanscape mode targets also the 1024px media query). Maybe thats the reason why all content gets out of place.

Comment: Also, the map is running fine in Google Developer Tools, using an iPad as test device in portrait mode. In one way or another, this is not what the iPad is showing.

Comment: Dont send the media query on different user agents. Always send them. Because, if you tilt the phone/device, the page does not get reloaded, just re-rendered. Send the mediaquery EVEN if you are positive you will not use it. Just to test, put the query, then resize your (PC) browser.

Comment: I've done those steps. Now, the media query steps are 1920px (iPhone landscape), 1024px (iPad landscape), 768px (iPad portrait), 640px (iPhone portrait). But the problem here is: I want to have the image of the woman hided on iPhone landscape, but visible on the iPad landscape (because the size of the small iPhone). But in pixels, de iPhone is bigger than the iPad. So in this situation, the iPad is hiding the image, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: The mediaquery system came into place, in order to make all mobile devices "behave" similarly... the fact that you can now see similar results is a good thing... I suggest you close down this question, and create a newwer one with the new scenario... in stackoverflow, each question is supposed to be about 1 subject, and new users may read on how to fix their problems.... Finally, you could use javascript or Jquery to fetch browser size, and act accordingly [check here](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/height/)